# Apply custom page template to content from Drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-fapi

I am developing a Drupal module. Part of it opens a pop-up window, displays some elements in it, and uses JavaScript to transfer input back to the main page.

As this is a small window, I don't want it to display the full theme borders from the site's theme.

In Drupal 6 I was able to achieve this with the following:

```
function MyPopupPageHandler() {
  @content = "Content...";
  //Add additional content to @content;
  print theme("page", @content);
}
```

However, Drupal 7 expects the second parameter of the theme() function to be an array, and none of the examples I've seen show how I set the main content of the page.

What I'd like is a custom page template in the module, that can be overridden by the site theme if it provides one.

I would like to know:

1. What elements do I need to put in the array I pass to the theme() function?
2. What should I call my template file?
3. How do I tell Drupal where to find my template, as it needs to be in the module by default?

Appreciate any help you can offer.

James

Comment: I think I've figured this out.

Comment: I spent last night relearning how to program for Drupal, and I needed to drop my D6 based approach and start again.

The page handler needs to return an array of form elements, and the they should be returned to the calling function rather than printed directly, so there's no need to call the theme() function directly. In the hook_theme function, I was then able to set the template to be used.

I will post a more detailed explanation later in case it's of assistance to anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
First of all create a menu in .module file

```
function MYMODULE_menu()
{
    $items['Demo'] =array(
            'title' => 'Demo Page',
            'page callback' => 'demo_page', // call a function
            'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
     return $items;

}
```

After you have create a function

```
function demo_page()
{
    $select = db_select('node', 'n');
    $select = $select->fields('n', array('id'))
    ->extend('PagerDefault');

    $queried_nodes = $select->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc('id');
    $pager = theme('pager');

    return  theme('demo_template', array('nodes' => $queried_nodes , 'pager' => $pager)); // call a theme or you have no pass any argument in theme to change a 'nodes'=> NULL or 'pager'=>NULL 
}
```

after i have create a theme function

```
function MYMODULE_theme()
{
    return array(
      'demo_template' => array(
        'template' => 'demo-page',//this is file name of template file
        'variables' => array('nodes' => NULL,'pager' => NULL), //this is pass avarible of templates file
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE_NAME').'/template' // set a path of file 
    ),
 );

}
```

after you have create file name like demo-page.tpl.php in sites/all/modules/MYMODULENAME/template/

and clear caches

Answer (score 0):

1) The second parameter of `theme()` function must be an associative array. Your function should look like :

```
function MYMODULE_custom_function() {
  $content = "Some stuff";
  return theme('MYMODULE_custom_output', array('content' => $content));
}
```

2) I guess you meant "Where should I call my template file?" In the `hook_theme()` function in your same `.module` file :

```
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_custom_output' => array(
      'variables' => array('content' => array()),
      // You can also use template file here : 'template' => 'MYMODULE-template'
      // OR use the following theme_function() if you don't want to create a new file
    ),
  );
}

// If you don't use template file
function theme_MYMODULE_custom_output($variables) {
  $output = // Arrange your html output here
  return $output;
}
```

3) To tell where to find your custom template file if you decide to use one, you can read this : https://drupal.org/node/715160 and I hope it will help.

Please stay indulgent because I'm still new with Drupal and I did try to do my best here :o)